# How to enable a dropdown is another dropdown is checked

Tags: jquery

I searched for decision of my question. I found some things but when I tried it, it didn't work.
I need when user is selected from first dropdown, next dropdown to be enabled. Else, if he hasn't selected from first dropdown, next dropdown to be disabled.
Here's what I tried:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#region').click(function() {
            if ($('#region').attr('checked')) {
          
              $( "#school" ).selectmenu( "enable" );
            } else {
              
              $( "#school" ).selectmenu( "disable" ); 
            }
       });
      });
```

```html
<select name='region'   id='region'>
  <option value="<?php echo set_select('gender'); ?>">Choose region</option>
     <option value="Region 1" >Region 1</option>
  <option value="Region 2" >Region 2</option> 
  </select>

<select name='school'   id='school'>
  <option value="<?php echo set_select('gender'); ?>">Choose school</option>
     <option value="School 1" >School 1</option>
  <option value="School 2" >School 2</option> 
  </select>
```

Now it's not disabled when user hasn't selected from first dropdown - region.
Please how to do that? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(function() { // Shorthand for $(document).ready(
    $('#region').change(function() {
        if($("#region").val() == "")
            $("#school").prop("disabled", true);
        else
            $("#school").prop("disabled", false);
    });
});
```

Take note that you should change the value of the "Choose region" option to "" or change "" on line 3 to whatever its default value is.

Comment: How it should be if I have following code: $(document).ready(function(){
      $(":radio").click(function(){
          $('#region').val('Choose region'); }); });

Comment: I tried with : $(function() { 
    $('#region').change(function() {
        if($("#region").val() == "Choose region")
            $("#school").prop("disabled", true);
        else
            $("#school").prop("disabled", false);
    });
});   and my select is: select name='region'   id='region' >
  <option value="">Choose region</option>
      <?php foreach ($regions as $row) { ?>
        <option name='region' value= "<?= $row->region ?>" 
        ><?= $row->region ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
  </select>  But it isn't disabled.;

Comment: You should use `$("#region").val("");` instead of `$("#region").val("Choose region");` since the value of the _Choose region_ option is in fact `""`

Comment: I tried now that, but when page onload, instead of "Choose region" in my dropdown there's empty value and when I click on dropdown and choose "Choose region", second dropdown is disabled as I wish. But why when page loads, it doesn't appear that "Chhose region", but I have to choose it from dropdown, it should be there.

Comment: I have : $(document).ready(function(){
      $(":radio").click(function(){
          $('#region').val('Choose region'); }); }); and my dropdown is: <select name='region'   id='region' >
  <option value="">Choose region</option>
      <?php foreach ($regions as $row) { ?>
        <option name='region' value= "<?= $row->region ?>" 
        ><?= $row->region ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
  </select>

Comment: You should add `disabled="disabled"` attribute to the school select, like this: `<select name="school" id="school" disabled="disabled">` or use the following javascript: `$(function(){
 if($("#region").val() == "")
 {
  $("#school").prop("disabled", true);
 } 
});`

Comment: Now, it is disabled, even when I choose region. I added to my select that: <select name='region'   id='region' >
  <option value="<?php echo set_select('region'); ?>">Choose region</option>
      <?php foreach ($regions as $row) { ?>
        <option name='region' value= "<?= $row->region ?>" 
        ><?= $row->region ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
  </select> but it's disabled again

Comment: It might be easier to understand if I show you a working example. You can view a fully working version here: https://jsfiddle.net/bs1dta4d/